# how to prevent adding duplicate keys to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, duplicates, key-value

I found a lot of related questions with answers talking about for...in loops and using hasOwnProperty but nothing I do works properly. All I want to do is check whether or not a key exists in an array and if not, add it.

I start with an empty array then add keys as the page is scrubbed with jQuery.

Initially, I hoped that something simple like the following would work: (using generic names)

```
if (!array[key])
   array[key] = value;
```

No go. Followed it up with:

```
for (var in array) {
   if (!array.hasOwnProperty(var))
      array[key] = value;
}
```

Also tried:

```
if (array.hasOwnProperty(key) == false)
   array[key] = value;
```

None of this has worked. Either nothing is pushed to the array or what I try is no better than simply declaring `array[key] = value` Why is something so simple so difficult to do. Any ideas to make this work?

Comment: you are trying on `Array` or `Object`?

Comment: ES6 now has [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) native

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is better accomplished with an object instead since JavaScript doesn't really have associative arrays:

```
var foo = { bar: 0 };
```

Then use `in` to check for a key:

```
if ( !( 'bar' in foo ) ) {
    foo['bar'] = 42;
}
```

As was rightly pointed out in the comments below, this method is useful *only* when your keys will be strings, or items that can be represented as strings (such as numbers).

Comment: ...assuming that your values are strings or representable as unique strings (this includes numbers).

Comment: @Phrogz Absolutely. Good bit of advice to the OP.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. The light FINALLY clicked as to what I was doing wrong. I was about to say your answer didn't help either but after a little more detective work, I'm pleased to say it worked perfectly. And thanks for the tips on Objects. I'll keep that in mind down the road.

Answer (score 43):

```
var a = [1,2,3], b = [4,1,5,2];

b.forEach(function(value){
  if (a.indexOf(value)==-1) a.push(value);
});

console.log(a);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

*For more details read up on [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).*

If you want to rely on jQuery, instead use [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
$.each(b,function(value){
  if ($.inArray(value,a)==-1) a.push(value);
});
```

**If all your values are simply and uniquely representable as strings**, however, you should use an Object instead of an Array, for a potentially *massive* speed increase (as described in the answer by @JonathanSampson).

Comment: Also, the problem with using `indexOf` is that it itself makes a loop... This makes for a [Schlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_Algorithm) that slows down with every item added to the array.

Answer (score 25):

A better alternative is provided in ES6 using Sets. So, instead of declaring Arrays, it is recommended to use Sets if you need to have an array that shouldn't add duplicates.

```
var array = new Set();
array.add(1);
array.add(2);
array.add(3);

console.log(array);
// Prints: Set(3) {1, 2, 3}

array.add(2); // does not add any new element

console.log(array);
// Still Prints: Set(3) {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Only works with primitive types, so sets are really limited.

Comment: @Erik: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set: The Set object lets you store **unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references**.

Comment: It accepts any values, but is not able to evaluate equality for non-primitives. http://jsfiddle.net/poLd7tk6/

Comment: from what I see, set returns an object not an array

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple way using spread.

This code will give duplicates:

```
let colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];
let moreColors = ['orange', 'green'];

// uh oh! this gives us 'orange' twice
let mergedColors = [...colors, ...moreColors];
```

So you can filter and remove them at the same time you merge the arrays.

```
let mergedColors = [...colors, ...moreColors.filter(c => !colors.includes(c)) ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(names, function(i, el){
if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
```

[Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong. Consider this:

```
x = ["a","b","c"]
x[0]     // "a"
x["0"]   // "a"
0 in x   // true
"0" in x // true
x.hasOwnProperty(0)   // true
x.hasOwnProperty("0") // true
```

There is no reason to loop to check for *key* (or *indices* for arrays) existence. Now, *values* are a different story...

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
function check (list){
    var foundRepeatingValue = false;
    var newList = [];
    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        var thisValue = list[i];
        if(i>0){
            if(newList.indexOf(thisValue)>-1){
                foundRepeatingValue = true;
                console.log("getting repeated");
                return true;
            }
       } newList.push(thisValue);
    } return false;
}
```

```
var list1 = ["dse","dfg","dse"];
check(list1);
```

Output:

```
getting repeated
true
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let x = "farceus";
let y = "character";

const commonCharacters = function (string1, string2) {
  let duplicateCharacter = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i += 1) {
    if (duplicateCharacter.indexOf(string1[i]) === -1) {
      if (string2.indexOf(string1[i]) !== -1) {
        duplicateCharacter += string1[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return [...duplicateCharacter];
};


console.log(commonCharacters(x, y));
```